# Set window position in the center

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have set the start position to manual somewhere around the top right of the screen in VS2012.
I am trying to later on set this window in the center with one click but no matter what I do its never in the center.. how can I do that?

Comment: You have set the position to manual and for a button click you want to center it ?

Comment: @AccessDenied on start its manual yes and on click i want it centered..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this code to your button click event,

```
this.Location = new Point((SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Width - this.Width) / 2, (SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Height - this.Height) / 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Form.CenterToScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.centertoscreen.aspx) method